# How do I classify new text using a classification model built in a different project?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk, text-classification

In the first project I have trained and pickled a classification model that uses bag of words with 2500 features, but in this new project I want to actually classify new text.

**How do I classify new text?**

This is what I'm doing:

```py
import pickle

# pickled TfidfVectorizer(max_features=2500)
vectorizer_in = open("vectorizer.pkl", "rb")
vectorizer = pickle.load(vectorizer_in)

# pickled RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 200, criterion = 'gini', class_weight="balanced")
classifier_in = open("classifier.pkl", "rb")
classifier = pickle.load(classifier_in)

# import libraries to clean the text
import re
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer('italian')
stopwords_set = set(stopwords.words('italian'))

# clean the input string
def cleanRow(row):
    row = re.sub('[\n|\r]', ' ', row)
    # regex here ...
    row = row.split()
    row = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in row if not word in stopwords_set]
    row = ' '.join(row)
    return row

def classify(summary, description):
    corpus = cleanRow(summary + " " + description)
    X_test = vectorizer.fit_transform([corpus]).toarray()
    print(vectorizer.get_feature_names()) # ['cas', 'computer', 'cos', 'funzion', 'part', 'pc', 'pi', 'tav']
    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
    # TODO map y_pred to the right label
    return y_pred

out = classify("il computer non parte", "Stavo facendo cose a caso e non mi funziona più il pc.")
print(out)
```

**This is the error generated:**

> `X has 8 features per sample; expecting 2500`

Indeed

```py
vectorizer.get_feature_names()
# ['cas', 'computer', 'cos', 'funzion', 'part', 'pc', 'pi', 'tav']
```

**but I want the original feature labels in the same order of when the model was created and trained**.

Should I pickle the original array of features and by hand rebuild a new bag of words table for the new text that I want to classify?

Comment: in a classify function , you have to use vectorizer.transform and not fit_transform..

Comment: @qaiser this solved the problem. You're right, there's no need to "fit" again

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment: "in a classify function, you have to use `vectorizer.transform` and not `fit_transform`".

Using

```py
X_test = vectorizer.transform([corpus]).toarray()
```

solves the problem, as it isn't fitting the model again, but only creating the term matrix as input of the classification.